# How can I select or remove specific element from vector in r?

Tags: r

I have a vector, like this:

```
tree <- c("Acer campestre", "Juglans regia", "Malus domestica", "Prunus avium")
```

I want to select or remove some trees, but in my cases, it is important to use the name of trees.
I have tried this:

```
my.tree <- tree[-c("Acer campestre", "Juglans nigra")]
```

but I got error message `"invalid argument to unary operator"`.

Comment: try: `my.tree <- tree[! tree %in% c("Acer campestre", "Juglans nigra")]`

Comment: Or `my.tree <- setdiff(tree, c("Acer campestre", "Juglans nigra"))`

Comment: @MaratTalipov, there's a potentially important difference between `setdiff` and `%in%`. The question doesn't provide enough information for us to know whether `setdiff` is a reasonable alternative.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, what is that potentially important difference?

Comment: @MaratTalipov, what would the result be if we were dealing with `tree <- c(tree, tree)` and you used `setdiff`? Simple illustration: `x <- rep(c("a", "b"), 10); setdiff(x, "b"); x[!x %in% "b"]`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, good point. It will be important in the context of subsetting a data frame, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
tree <- c("Acer campestre", "Juglans regia", "Malus domestica", "Prunus avium")
to_remove <- c("Acer campestre", "Juglans nigra")
my.tree <- tree[!tree %in% to_remove]
```

`%in%` compares two vectors while `!` negates the call. All together basically means `tree` vector where any of elements is NOT in `to_remove` vector.

Answer (score 0):

Well, another way is you can use the index positions

```
my.tree <- tree[-c(1,2)]
```

and if they are large in number you can also use the ' : ' operator

```
my.tree <- tree[-(1:2)]
```